# how to make perspective effect bigger while rotating along X direction?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-8, winrt-xaml

i am doing winrt application,i want to rotate an image along X direction, i did this using ***Planeprojection*'s**  *RotationX* Property. but i want it more perspective manner,i mean it should look like bigger while rotating, how it could be possible?

Comment: You could use a storyboard and also animate the height and the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a composite transition including skew, scale transform